# Real-time node form

Tags: forms, nodes

Is there a way for users to see the choices he/she already made on the form on real-time? For example a user clicked a checkbox or radio button and on the bottom part of the form it shows all the choices he/she made without saving it yet. Basically its like a summary of all the choices the user made on the bottom part of the form without actually saving the form.

I've been trying this for a while now, any help or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery. 
For example, at bottom of your form you can append new container:

`$('.your_form').append('<div class="summary"></div>');`

and then by adding to your input elements click/change listeners add their values to your new container:

`$( "#name input" ).change(function() {
  $('.summary').html($( this ).val());
});`

Comment: Paul Nike thanks for your answer, I've tried it and it worked! Thanks man. I have another question though bcoz I'm actually using entity reference for the choices on the radio button to filter certain types of nodes. When I click on a radio button on the form only the NID of the choice appears on the <div class="summary"></div> but what I want is the title of the node not the NID, do you know how to call the title on jqeury?

Comment: You need to write small module for form_alter, something like this 

`function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {

    $options = $form['your_radios']['#options'];
    $new_options = array();
 foreach($options as $key->$value){
  $node = node_load($key);
  $new_options[$node->title] = $value;
 }
 $form['your_radios']['#options'] = $new_options;
  }
}`
With debugger this task will be done easier. Another way is to write ajax function in your menu callback, but I think first way is much easier.

Comment: sorry, in foreach($options as $key->$value) typo. Correct version is foreach($options as $key=>$value)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I haven't had time to try it yet but I will later. :) Wish there was an easier way though than creating a custom module.